# Cannot print author name and affiliation in amsart document class

Tags: author

Using the following preamble I am not getting any author name displayed in the pdf. Can anyone please tell me why this is happening?

```
\documentclass[twoside,reqno,10pt]{amsart}
\raggedbottom 

% Packages for mathematics and symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}    % Enhanced math formatting and symbols
\usepackage{amssymb}    % Additional math symbols, for circlearrowleft. 
\usepackage{amsthm}     % Theorem environments
\usepackage{amsfonts}   % Math fonts
\usepackage{mathtools}  % Extends amsmath
\usepackage{bbm}        % For "\mathbb{1}"
\usepackage{dsfont}     % for bold faces "1". 
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}

% Graphics and diagrams
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Include graphics
\usepackage{tikz-cd}    % Commutative diagrams

% Page layout and formatting
\usepackage{geometry}   % Page layout
\usepackage{setspace}   % Adjust line spacing
\usepackage{enumerate}  % Custom enumeration lists

% Bibliography
\usepackage{cite}

% Additional packages
\usepackage{hyperref}   % Hyperlinks within the document
\usepackage{comment}    % To use the "comment" envioronment. 
\usepackage{authblk}    % For author information. 


% Title and author information
% Document metadata
\title{Your Title}
\author[F1.LastName1]{FirstName1 LastName1}
\address{Address1}
\email{First1.Last1@domain.com}
\author[F2.LastName2]{FirstName2 LastName2}
\address{Address2}
\email{First2.Last2@domain.com}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
```

The title is getting printed. But no author name shows up in the pdf.

Comment: Firstly, the abstract should come before the `\maketitle` when using the `amsart` document class. This is stated explicitly in the class documentation.

Comment: Also, do you need *all* of those packages in your example? Do you still encounter your issue if you remove most/all of those packages? Please make sure that your example is *minimal* if possible.

Comment: remove `\usepackage{authblk}`.